# Accessing Android app assets with Cordova file plugin

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, phonegap-plugins

I need to access some of my app's assets on Android using the file plugin (latest version). The following works on iOS but always fails on Android:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/" + dirName, success_function(), fail_function())
```

In config.xml I have:

```
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,root" />
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

I see this issue crop up regularly but I've not yet come across an answer that works.